# Firefox Extension - Wrong charset?

Tags: firefox, character-encoding

If within a Firefox extension I write:

gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = "†";

I get a � character.

Any Ideia on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Write the character in the target page's encoding, or use an HTML entity `&dagger;` †

Comment: I had to specify the charset in the origin and in the endpoint :p but got it sorted. tx